# Jquery Mobile 1.4.0 on Flip Switch event handling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do we add an event handler for a flipswitch in JqueryMobile 1.4.0
I have a flip switch like

```
<input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox" id="flip-checkbox">
```

The event handler as mentioned in the documentation is

```
$( "#flip-checkbox" ).on( "flipswitchcreate", function( event, ui ) { alert("Flip    Switched"); } );
```

I also tried using $.click() and $.change(). But nothing is triggered upon change  of the flip switch. How do we handle this?

Comment: `$( "#flip-checkbox" ).on( "change", function () { });` should work with no issues. Make sure your HTML markup is correct.

Comment: @Omar `$( "#flip-checkbox" ).on( "change", function () { });` does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

use it like so

```
$( document ).on( "change", "#flip-checkbox",  function( event, ui ) {
 alert("Flip    Switched"); 
} );
```